# How the ssh signal is propagated and realized in paramiko？

Tags: ssh, paramiko, django-channels, xtermjs

I am currently using django and vue to develop a web page to connect to the command line of a remote host. I would like to know how to implement the function of reviewing input commands, such as prohibiting users from operating on the network or disk.[web terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz7nM.png)

The module I use is invoke_shell(), It seems that it can only capture the typing of the keyboard, and then directly interact with the remote host. When I press the up key, the content of the previous command is directly displayed on the front end, and the content of this command is currently not found in the back end.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to implement a filter on top of live terminal that would prevent certain dangerous actions. I wouldn't dare to try to do that. Users will always find a way to circumvent your "filters".

Comment: This can only securely prevented by intercepting things within the shell/REPL, which evals the command strings to be executed. I dont think you want to fork & alter bash to get there. An easier way is to downstrip the env the user runs, like a docker/chroot env restricting access to certain endpoints and binaries (no root privileges, no kernel stuff, no network access, no binary xy...)